# Update a view doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-view

I'm working on a view which is then updated by the user. This update basically changes the value of column. But right now it doesnt let me do that and produces this :

```
Update or insert of view or function '' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

I know this is because I have a constant in the select statement but is there a way to get around it? Please help

This is my code for the view

```
Create view Schema.View1
as
SELECT
Convert(Varchar(20),l.jtpName) as JobType, Convert(Varchar(10),' <All> ')as SubCategory , Convert(varchar (3), Case when a.jtpName= l.jtpName and a.subName= ' <All> ' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) As AutoProcess from Schema.JobType l left join Schema.Table1 a on l.jtpName=a.jtpName
UNION
SELECT
Convert(Varchar(20),a.jtpName) as JobType, Convert(Varchar(10),a.subName) as SubCategory, Convert(varchar (3),Case when b.jtpName= a.jtpName and b.subName= a.subName then 'Yes' else 'No' end) As AutoProcess from Schema.SubCategory a left join fds.Table1 b on a.subName=b.subName

GO
```

Finally the update statement:

```
UPDATE Schema.View1 SET AUTOPROCESS = Case WHEN AUTOPROCESS = 'Yes' Then 'No' END Where JOBTYPE = 'Transport' and SUBCATEGORY= 'Cargo'
```

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You cannot update a column that is the result of a computation.**

According to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), one of the conditions for a view column to be updatable is this:

- Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from only one base table.
- The columns being modified in the view must **directly reference the underlying data** in the table columns. The columns cannot be derived in any other way, such as through the following:

  - An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
  - A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators **UNION**, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a computation and are also not updatable.
- The columns being modified are not affected by GROUP BY, HAVING, or DISTINCT clauses.
- TOP is not used anywhere in the select_statement of the view together with the WITH CHECK OPTION clause.

Here not only does your view uses the `UNION` statement, the `AutoProcess` field you are trying to update is actually the result of a `CASE` statement that uses two fields. It makes no sense to try and update that.

I would recommend that you use stored proc to perform writing operations. Or, as Damien suggest, you could use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view too.

Comment: Ah thanks that document is very helpful. I guess I'll have to create another table and feed the values of this view into it and then update the table rather than the view.

Comment: @crunchynutter I don't think you should create a table just so that you can handle an update operation. Use a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a [`TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) and manually apply the changes from the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables against the base tables yourself.

Comment: @Crono - if the OP wants to be able to write `UPDATE`s against the view, and SQL Server has (quite rightly) decided that the view is not updatable, the only viable approach is to write triggers on the view that implements the required actions manually.

Comment: @Crono - I have linked to the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) documentation in my answer: `CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name ON { table | view } ...`

Comment: Wow! I didn't even knew it was possible! Hats off to you, sir! +1

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for sql server to work backwards from your convert functions to the original fields.   You cannot update a view this way.

If the view contained your jptName and subName fields, you might be able to update just those fields.

Comment: He wouldn't be able to update just these fields as they would still be the result of an `UNION` statement.